# Oracle - ALTER TABLE ENABLE TABLE LOCK

Tags: oracle, alter

I did `ALTER TABLE DISABLE TABLE LOCK` on one of our tables and now I can't enable table lock back. When I'm executing on this table:

```
ALTER TABLE x ENABLE TABLE LOCK;
```

I'm getting:

> SQL Error: ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

I checked that there was a blocking session from other user but he killed his session and now I still can't enable table lock. There is new locking session, looking like some system session (OSUSER=SYSTEM, PROGRAM=ORACLE.EXE (DIA0), TYPE=BACKGROUND).

Could you please help me with this enable table lock?

Edit: After database restart we were able to enable table lock.

Comment: That's a diagnostic process: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/REFRN/bgprocesses.htm#REFRN104

Comment: Other user killed session but if the session was updating or inserting rollback is being performed.

Comment: Try `ALTER SESSION SET DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT = 600;` before you try to lock the table. Oracle will wait up to 10 minutes till you get this error where other sessions can finish their jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Run this query to identify the sessions that are locking your object:

```
select
   c.owner,
   c.object_name,
   c.object_type,
   b.sid,
   b.serial#,
   b.status,
   b.osuser,
   b.machine
from
   v$locked_object a ,
   v$session b,
   dba_objects c
where
   b.sid = a.session_id
and
   a.object_id = c.object_id;
```

With results from this query you can run `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#';` that should clear the locks and you can retry acquiring the lock.

If you are having a process that re-spawns and  acquires the lock before your session you can, you can write a while loop that checks if the lock can be acquired by catching the ORA-00054 error and retrying until the lock can be placed using `LOCK TABLE x IN EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT;`

Comment: My table does not exists in v$locked_object. I can see only BLOCKING_SESSION in v$session when I'm trying to enable table lock. After blocking session kill I still can't enable lock, because always next session is blocking my session.

Comment: A quick workaround is to run a CTAS: `CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT * FROM old_table);` and alter the newly created table and after that, drop the old_table and rename the newly created one [oracle doc about rename table](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljrenametablestatement.html)

Comment: Another idea could be that you have something stuck in your current session, and you should try running it again from a new clean session.

Comment: Sebz when table is in DISABLE TABLE LOCK I can't drop it.

Comment: Yes, any lock acquiring on that table will fail if it's in that state. Run `ALTER TABLE table_name ENABLE TABLE LOCK` so you can acquire table locks again.

Comment: But the whole problem is that I can't execute ALTER TABLE table_name ENABLE TABLE LOCK

Comment: What user own this object and with what user are you trying to perform the alter?

Comment: I'm executing ALTER TABLE x ENABLE TABLE LOCK from user who is owner of this table.

Comment: Can you please try it running it as SYS?